# improve fit of polyval and polyfit

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

Can anyone help me to get a better fit on this curve? The plot shows test data for compression on an elastomer. The blue dots are the data, the red line is the 3rd order fit. If I increase the order of the fit the situation doesn't improve much.

I can supply the test data file if desired (There are 236 rows and 3 columns).

My code is given here:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy.polynomial.polynomial as poly
from itertools import islice
with open('neoprene1.csv') as f:
    readCSV = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    Cs = []
    Rs = []

    for row in islice(readCSV,1,None):
        R = row[1] if row[1] != '' else 0.0 # Strain
        C = row[2] if row[2] != '' else 0.0 # Stress

        Rs.append(R)
        Cs.append(C)

q = np.array([Rs],dtype = float).transpose()
s = np.array([Cs],dtype = float).transpose()

q1 = q[:,0]
s1 = s[:,0]
plt.cla()
z = poly.polyfit(q1,s1,3)
zz = poly.polyval(q,z)
plt.title('Neoprene True Stress-Strain')
plt.xlabel('Strain (%)')
plt.ylabel('Stress (MPa)')
aa = plt.plot(s1,zz,'r-', label = 'Fitting function')
bb = plt.plot(s1,q1,'bo', label = 'Raw data')
```

[image: Neoprene compression]

Comment: Try adding a sigmoid to your fit function - the errors look like they have the form of a sigmoid. This would require a more general regression approach than `polyfit`.

Comment: The purpose of a fit is usually to get some physical parameters out to verify (or falsify) a model. Unless you have a clear explanation in mind why this hysterisis curve should follow a polynomial law, it's probably totally inadequate to use a polynomial fit. In any case it would make strong sense to fit both arms of the curve separately or use a model function which includes the splitting.

Comment: for modeling hysteresis https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1701/1701.08070.pdf looks good, but I couldn't find the promised Mathcad worksheet

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone, much appreciated. @ImportanceOfBeingErnest - The purpose of the fit in this case is not to verify the model - I require the data to be monotonically increasing (which it, isn't ever so slightly). My plan was to get a fit as close as possible to the curve and use that as the model data instead, thus forcing a strictly increasing curve.

Comment: In that case treating each branch separately is the way to go. But instead of a polynomial fit you would probably want to perform some smoothing spline interpolation.